# How to perform login redirect using MSAL in Angular2

Tags: angular, authentication, redirect, angular2-services, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to do a B2C Azure authentication with MSAL library in Angular2. The login page is perfectly getting redirected to the Azure page and prompting the user for Username and  Password. After clicking the signin button and the authentication is successful, the page has to redirect itself back to my application landing page and set the 'user' object to one that is acquired from the AzureAD. Although the authentication is successful the user object is not getting set and the application fails.

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from 'app/services/auth.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
    providers: [AuthService]
})
@Injectable()
export class AppComponent {
    public user:Msal.User;
    public userInfo: any = null;
    public apiCallFailed: boolean;
    public loginFailed: boolean;

    constructor(private authService: AuthService,
                private partnerService: PartnerService) {
                  authService.user$.subscribe((newUser: Msal.User) => {
                    console.log('change detected');
                     this.user = newUser;
                    });
    }

    public login() {
        this.loginFailed = false;
        this.authService.login()
      //
    }
```

auth.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import '../../../node_modules/msal/out/msal';
/// <reference path="../../../node_modules/msal/out/msal.d.ts" />
import { WindowRef } from '../windowRef';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  private applicationConfig: any = {
    clientID: '**************************',
    authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/*********",
    b2cScopes: ["some.scope"],
    webApi: 'http://localhost:3000/api/partners',
    redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:6420'
  };
  private app: any;      
  private user =new Subject<Msal.User>();
  user$ = this.user.asObservable();

  constructor(private winRef: WindowRef) {
    this.app = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(this.applicationConfig.clientID, this.applicationConfig.authority,
      (errorDesc, token, error, tokenType) => {
        console.log(this.winRef.nativeWindow.msal.getUser())
        this.user.next(this.winRef.nativeWindow.msal.getUser());
      }
    );
  }
  public login() {
    return this.app.loginRedirect(this.applicationConfig.b2cScopes)

  }
```

I am totally new to Angular2 and in the beginning phase of the learning curve. After some reading I figured out observable was the way to move forward (I could be wrong) and made the user object in the service 'Observable' and the component to subscribe to it so that any changes in the user object by service can be captured and acted upon it by the compoenet. But it isnt working.

app.component.html

```
<button (click)="login()" type="button" *ngIf="!user">Login</button>
<button (click)="callAPI()" type="button" *ngIf="user">Call API</button>
<button (click)="logout()" type="button" *ngIf="user">Logout</button>
```

As in the above code,even after successfull authentication, I am getting only the 'login' button (because the user is not set) and not the other buttons as expected. Any help leading me to right direction would be greatly appreciated.